# How can i do a trigger update for a single person

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a bitacora of people where they enter the personal records of a person and its user and mail, for the part of registry it keeps all the data to me well, but at the moment of making a trigger of update it makes the modification to me in all the registries of That person specifically what is the part of user and mail, I am using this code to do the trigger of Update

```
CREATE TRIGGER Usuarios_AModificar AFTER UPDATE ON usuarios FOR EACH ROW UPDATE bitacorapersonas SET usuarioNuevo = NEW.usuario, correoNuevo = NEW.correo, correoViejo=old.correo,activacionNueva = new.activacion, activacionVieja=old.activacion WHERE cedula = NEW.usuarios_cedula
```

My table is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `correo` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_session` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `activacion` int(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `token` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `token_password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password_request` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id_tipo` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `usuarios_cedula` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



    CREATE TABLE `personas` (
      `cedula` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
      `nombres` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `apellidos` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `sexo` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      `telefono` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `direccion` text NOT NULL,
      `fnacimiento` date NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My table of bits is the following

```
CREATE TABLE `bitacorapersonas` (
  `idBitacora` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `accion` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `cedUsuario` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombreUsuario` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `tipoUsuario` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `cedula` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `nombreNuevo` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombreViejo` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apellidoNuevo` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellidoViejo` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sexoNuevo` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `sexoViejo` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefonoNuevo` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `telefonoViejo` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `direccionNuevo` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `direccionViejo` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fnacimientoNuevo` date NOT NULL,
  `fnacimientoViejo` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `usuarioNuevo` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `correoNuevo` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `correoViejo` varchar(15) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I do not know because when updating a data of a person example what is mail and user the first time does it well and when I modify for the second time the first record is also changed

I already put the where cedula = users_cedula but still changing all the records of that person and that is what misses me

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. You also didn't add the `bitacorapersonas`-table. Is it some kind of history table or a table of registry requests? Then just insert there, don't update. If not: you will have to figure out which row you want to update, as currently, you update every row with `WHERE cedula = NEW.usuarios_cedula`. We have no clue which (single) row you might mean.

Comment: I already put the where cedula = users_cedula but still changing all the records of that person and that is what misses me @Solarflare

Answer (score 0):

Before your next test, run this select statement and print the results.

```
select * from bitcorapersonas where cedula = <your test cedula>.
```

These are the rows that will be updated by your trigger.  To update a unique row, your where clause needs to have a unique condition.  It's not clear what that is from the question so I can't tell you how to update the trigger.  But I'm guessing you need to use usarios.id in you triggers where clause.

In your comment, you say you want a new row in the blog after updating an email.  In that case, you need an insert not an update.  If you want to update the original blog the first time an email is added and add rows other times, you need to determine that it's the first time in your trigger as follows:

```
if OLD.email is null then
   UPDATE <Your Update statement here> 
else
   INSERT <Your insert statement here>
```

Comment: What I need to do is if for example I modify the email of john for the first time, that is shown in the blog the changes that I made, then if I modify a next time the mail of john I need to appear in a next row of the blog, because Is another modification that I did, not that I update the same previous one of Juan where I change for the first time Juan . That's why I did that trigger update with that where

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER Usuarios_AModificar AFTER UPDATE ON usuarios FOR EACH ROW UPDATE bitacorapersonas SET usuarioNuevo = NEW.usuario, correoNuevo = NEW.correo, correoViejo=old.correo WHERE cedula = NEW.usuarios_cedula 
But it always does the same to me, it updates the data of the first record in the blog

Comment: And if I already have a insert trigger like I do? Because they are going to be activated every time you do in first, as you can have the (insert / update / delete) trigger for the same table, you can?

Comment: @Lissi29 If you already have an insert trigger, why do you need the update?  If you're trying to update an existing record, you need to know the unique key to that record.